# Как парсить строку?

Tags: php

Не могу понять, как парсить строку:

```
useriata({"iata":"MOW","name":"Москва"})
```

Это и не массив, и не json.

Comment: Это именно строка, то есть `$data = 'useriata({"iata":"MOW","name":"Москва"})'`?

Comment: @PinkTux отправляю запрос к API, а оно мне возвращает строку `useriata({"iata":"MOW","name":"Москва"})`

Comment: А, так это travelpayouts? Во-первых, они умеют отдавать JSON, надо покопаться в девелоперской документации. Во-вторых, можно просто вырезать обвязку `useriata(...)` и парсить как обычный JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Этот формат передачи данных называется [JSONP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

А парсить его очень просто: выкусываете оборачивающую функцию и парсите JSON стандартными средствами.

Например так:

```
$jsonp_data = 'useriata({"iata":"MOW","name":"Москва"})';
$json = preg_replace('/^[^\(]+\((.*)\)$/', '$1', $jsonp_data);

var_dump(json_decode($json));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вероятнее всего - это JSONP. В таком случае можно просто выкинуть `^useriata(\{` и `\)$` (не силен в синтаксисе регулярок, но суть в удалении начала и конца строки)